# loop through a column and add the last values in r

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame that such as below. I want to add the last value in the column of the last three month. In this case, it will be 6 + 7 + 0 = 13. How can i write the for loop to add the numbers in R

```
df <- read.table(textConnection('
mth     n value    
jan     1 5      
feb     2 1  
feb     2 3   
mar     3 2  
mar     3 8  
mar     3 0  
apr     4 6  
apr     4 0  
apr     4 2  
apr     4 7  
may     5 2  
may     5 1  
may     5 4  
may     5 2  
may     5 6  
'), header=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tapply` treats mth as a string unless it's converted to a factor. Another approach for hard coding month which, using only 3, is more readable:

```
df$mth <- factor(df$mth, levels=c('jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may'))
sum(tail(tapply(df$value, df$mth, tail, 1), 3))
```

Another approach

```
sum(tapply(df$value, df$mth, tail, 1)[c('mar', 'apr', 'may')])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer

- Using data.table
- as the data appeared originally, hopefully can be adopted if data is. different

---

**Solution**

```
library(data.table)
dt[, value[.N], mth][(.N-2):.N, sum(V1)]
[1] 13
```

**Data**

```
dt <- structure(list(mth = c("jan", "feb", "feb", "mar", "mar", "mar", 
                       "apr", "apr", "apr", "apr", "may", "may", "may", "may", "may"
), n = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
         5L, 5L), value = c(5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 
                            1L, 4L, 2L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                 "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **tidyverse**:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    arrange(n) %>% 
    group_by(mth) %>%
    slice(n()) %>% 
    arrange(n) %>% 
    tail(3) %>% 
    ungroup(mth) %>% 
    summarise(sum_value = sum(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `dplyr` can be as:

library(dplyr)

```
df %>% group_by(n,  mth) %>%
  summarise(last_value = last(value)) %>%
  tail(3) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(last_value))

# # A tibble: 1 x 1
# sum
# <int>
#   1    13
```